# How to change location of AVD (Android Virtual Devices) files to external SSD in macOS?

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device

System Info: macOS 12.7
Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 3
Runtime version: 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231 aarch64

By default, avd files will be stored in "/Users/xxx/.android/avd".

But macOS ran out of storage and I wanted to move it to an external hard drive. It seems Android Studio doesn't offer the option to modify avd paths.

I would be grateful if you have any solutions.

I tried to add the "ANDROID_SDK_HOME" environment variable to ~/.zshrc, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

check these they are from another stack exchange. I recommended these as nothing you tried is mentioned in your post.

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/218796/how-to-change-location-of-avd-android-virtual-devices-files-to-external-ssd

https://dev.to/oscherler/move-android-studio-virtual-devices-on-a-mac-5ej5